# Error: Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_NOT_PAID in Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

When reviewing the release for my Android app in the Google Play Developer platform I receive this message as a blocking error Unknown validation VALIDATE_APP_MESSAGE_NOT_PAID.

I was unable to locate any reference to the error in any Google documentation and the solutions in the other stack overflow posts (try changing the price of your app, or making it paid and then free again and saving) have failed to fix it. I also tried creating a new release from scratch to no avail.

I have an open ticket with Google Support atm but taking forever to respond and this app is rather time sensitive.

Anyone experience this or something similar and resolved the issue, or maybe even some Google Play Devs out there that could lend a hand would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any email about that error?

Comment: Yes I did but only after I'd managed to fix it by creating an entirely new organisation from scratch. It appears the issue was in fact with the console and not my release.
----- This was their Message -----
Thanks for your patience while our team investigated the behavior you experienced and apologies for the inconvenience this may have caused.

They have recently made some changes that should fix the problem. With the recent set of changes, please check to see if you are still experiencing the same issue. If so, I will be happy to see how else we can help

Comment: Ok, great, glad that you managed. Might be good to post this solution you got, as direct answer. So that anybody else with the same problem, can see it what & why did that happen.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating an entirely new organisation in the play console. The only solution to this problem is through Google Support fixing it on the back end it seems.

----- This was the Message from Google Dev Support -----

Thanks for your patience while our team investigated the behavior you experienced and apologies for the inconvenience this may have caused. They have recently made some changes that should fix the problem. With the recent set of changes, please check to see if you are still experiencing the same issue. If so, I will be happy to see how else we can help.